# How to use germ_terms() with meta_query for ACF Taxonomy field?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, terms

I have a custom taxonomy, Events (“event”).

Through ACF, this also has a Taxonomy field, “Topic”, linking it to a secondary taxonomy, Topic (“topic”).

I want to `get_terms()` for all Events terms which bear the specific “Topic” term “Media”, which happens to have term ID 422.

I know `get_terms()` can take meta_query, but I don’t understand how to properly get what I need.

Both of these return no results…

```
'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'Topic',
          'value'   => '422',
        )
      )

'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'Topic',
          'value'   => 422,
        )
      )
```

FYI, my “Topic” Taxonomy ACF field “Return Value” is set to “Term ID”, which is why I attempted passing ‘422’.

As it happens, to test, when I…

– do a get_terms() without meta_query

– then get_term_meta() to get the “Topic” of the terms

– then print out the result…

… I see a formulation like `Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 422 ) )`

That’s where the 422 is buried.

Answer (score 0):

Answer - the correct formulation is...

`'meta_query' => array(
        array(
          'key'     => 'Topic',
          'value'   => "12057",
          'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
      )`

In full:

`    $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'event',
      // 'order' => 'ASC',
      'hide_empty' => false,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      // 'parent' => 0,

```
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key'     => 'Topic',
      'value'   => "12057",
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )


);

$events = get_terms( $args );`
```

Specifically, it seems `'compare' => 'LIKE'` needs to be present.

Initially, I had thought the solution was to use double quotes on the value, which I inferred from @hube2's response to [another question](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/query-posts-by-taxonomy-field/).

But actually it works with single or double. The clincher is the present of `'compare' => 'LIKE'`.

Answer (score 0):

`'compare' => 'IN'` Since you're comparing against a single value, you can use `IN` as the comparison operator.

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'event',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'topic', // Meta key for ACF Taxonomy field
            'value' => 422, // Term ID to match
            'compare' => 'IN', // Match any of the provided values
        ),
    ),
);

$terms = get_terms( $args );
```